# Chain http call with retrofit and rxjava

Tags: android, reactive-programming

I have one call to get a list of team. Each team has an id and let me to make new requests with theses ids.

*Example: Team*

```
{
    "id": 1
    "name": "test",
}
```

*Example: User*

```
{
    "name": "user1",
    "lvl": 42
}
```

One team is composed of multiple users.

I have created these models. My first call gives me a list of team and foreach team i need to know the users. So here is my code with retrofit and rxjava.

```
mTeamApi.teams(userId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .flatMap(new Func1<TeamTop, Observable<Team>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Team> call(TeamTop teamTop) {
                        return Observable.from(teamTop.getTeams());
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<Team, Observable<MemberTop>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<MemberTop> call(Team team) {
                        return mTeamApi.usersOfTeam(team.getId());
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<MemberTop>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Utils.manageWsError(e, callback);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(MemberTop data) {
                        callback.showMembers(data.getUsers());
                    }
                });
```

The result gives me a list of all users but i would like add a field in **Team** objet like *'users'* and foreach **Team** fill this field with users. So my expected result is a list of team

If you have the solution, you know what to do :)